# code=StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, details="OS Error"

Tags: tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I deployment my own model with tensorflow serving. Usually it works without problems, but sometimes it gets such an error message:

```
AbortionError(code=StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, details="OS Error")
```

I don't know why, anybody can help me ?

My code:

```
channel = implementations.insecure_channel(tfserving_food_cls_host, int(tfserving_foodcls_port))
            stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
            serving_request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
            serving_request.model_spec.name = 'default'
            serving_request.model_spec.signature_name = 'predict_images'

            serving_request.inputs['images'].CopyFrom(
                tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image299,
                                                  shape=[1, 299, 299, 3]))
            serving_results = stub.Predict(serving_request, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an OS error, as the log said? Have you tried another host?